# Photoshop has much bigger pixel width than the actual element in a browser

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Why? I do a screenshot of let's say 960px wide element and it has about 1400px in Photoshop.
Zoom level is 100%

---

I guess it's due to Windows rescaling.

Comment: What's your monitor resolution? I think you already answered your own question.